# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 IIS server

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I want to send (POST) a text data with my URL "http" no "https" in Xcode 7 - iOS 9. But I have this Error:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be
>   loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a
>   secure connection." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7f963a7c8690 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "(null)"},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://html2servhe.myDomain.com/JsonWcfService/GetEmployees.svc/json/Sendamail/MyName/Mymail@gmail.com/2222,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://html2servhe.myDomain.com/JsonWcfService/GetEmployees.svc/json/Sendamail/MyName/Mymail@gmail.com/2222,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the
>   App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure
>   connection.}

I have configurated my info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

My code is this:

NSString *str = CadenaConParametros;

```
NSURL *WcfSeviceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:WcfSeviceURL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error: nil];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:WcfSeviceURL completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:data
                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                              error:&error];
        NSString *isSuccessNumber = (NSString*)[json objectForKey:@"InsertEmployeeMethodResult"];
    }
}];

[task resume];
```

This worked in iOS 8, and I try with the URL in POSTMAN (app of Google Chrome) and works.

What is wrong?
thanks.